# Returning .msg file is empty string when it is not

Tags: python, file, text, msg

Hey everyone this is my first question I've asked here so I'm sorry if my formatting might be off.

I have a folder with 11,000 .msg files and I need to iterate over them and print the second line of each file to a .txt file.

The loop I'm currently running is this

```
s = ""
for filename in os.listdir('DIRECTORY/files'):
    if filename.endswith(".msg"):
       line = linecache.getline(filename, 2)
       s += line + "\n"
       continue
text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
text_file.write(s)
text_file.close()
```

Python is finding all the .msg files fine but returns that the second line is an empty string. If I take about 5 files out of the /files directory and run my loop over them I get my desired output (which looks like)

```
"Return-path: <SOME@EMAIL.com>"
```

furthermore if I run

```
line = linecache.getline("files/FILENAME.msg", 2)
print(line)
```

I get my desired output. I'm at a loss of what is wrong with my code or what's going on.

Comment: What is `linecache` for ?

Comment: It's a python library, it's opening just the second line instead of opening every line I believe https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html

Comment: I see now that it says it'll return ' ' on errors so that's what is giving the blank string but I still don't know why it's not working when I loop inside the big directory...

Comment: I guess you need to use `clearcache()` as well and also mind that **This function will never raise an exception — it will return '' on errors**

Comment: **Premature optimization is the root cause of Evil**

Comment: I added `linecache.clearcache()` but I still get a empty string when I loop through the entire directory.

Comment: Then remove the linecache thing and try with simple `open` method

Comment: Okay I will do that and report back, thanks!

Comment: Holy that formatting just did not work, I changed the loop to look like

http://pastebin.com/GiC1pTj0

It get's about 3/4 of the way through the files then raises an exception 

"No such file or directory: 'md50000009700.msg'" which does exist. Do you think the problem could be my string `s` is becoming too large?

Comment: Nopes, it is python can handle pretty large strings :)

Comment: hmm well I'll keep plugging away then, hopefully I can get it to work.